# How to target a Div in CSS in Rmarkdown HTML

Tags: html, css, r-markdown

[image]

I'd like to be able to control the header of this HTML file with CSS inside Rmarkdown. I want to change the text size, but can't seem to control it, here is what I have tried

```
div.header.fluid-row {
  font-size: 12;
}

div.fluid-row {
  font-size: 12;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe so?

```css
.fluid-row .title {
  font-size: 12px;
}

/*    OR    */

.fluid-row h1 {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```